# Generate a bad certificate

Tags: openssl

I want to test my server for bad certificates.
How can I generate certificates with wrong:
Version
Serial Number
Algorithm ID
Issuer
Valid From - Not Before
Valid To - Not After
Subject
Public Key Algorithm
Subject Public Key
Issuer Unique Identifier
Certificate Signature Algorithm
Certificate Signature
Extensions
Basic Constraints
Key Usage
Extended Key Usage

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by bad certificate? Why any self signed certificate will not help you?

Comment: I think the word is more a fake certificate. I guess he wants to try how his application will respond to certificate with bad data.

Comment: Exactly - want to verify that I get the right warning for each case. Thanks